Radial hyperbolic trajectories
Wikipedia informs me that

In astrodynamics and celestial mechanics a radial trajectory is a Kepler orbit with zero angular momentum. Two objects in a radial trajectory move directly towards or away from each other in a straight line.

and further states that a radial hyperbolic orbit is

a non-periodic orbit where the relative speed of the two objects always exceeds the escape velocity.

which seems straightforward enough. It then goes on to provide a slightly dubious equation for the time taken to for the objects to reach a given separation:
$$t( x, w ) =  \frac{ \sqrt{ (|w|x)^2 + |w|x} - \ln\left(\sqrt{|w|x} + \sqrt{1 + |w|x}\right) }{ \sqrt{2\mu \, |w|^3} }$$
where $x$ is the separation and $w$ is a negative magic number defined elsewhere in the article. Unfortunately, this equation seems incorrect (what are the units for $(|w|x)^2 + |w|x$, for example?), and the article doesn't cite a source. I can't seem to find any source for a correct version of the equation, and I've been unable to find anything else relevant for radial hyperbolic orbits, rather than the regular kind.
Can anyone tell me what the correct form of this equation is? Or alternatively, that it is perfectly fine as it is and I'm just holding it wrong?

The Wikipedia page's external links include https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s4-03/4-03.htm and Eq. 3 near the bottom looks similar. That's not much help but it's something at least.

$w$ is in units of inverse distance, $x$ is in units of distance, so as long as the units  are consistent,  the  units of $|w|x$  cancel out.

Note that $w$ is simply half of the inverse of the semi-major axis length ($w \equiv \frac1{2a}$), so $w$ has units of $L^{-1}$ (inverse length), making $|w|x$ be unitless. Also note that the semi-major axis length is negative for a hyperbolic trajectory, which is why that equation has so many absolute value symbols. Personally, I would use negative signs as $w$ is known to be negative in this case.


$$t( x, w ) =  \frac{ \sqrt{ (|w|x)^2 + |w|x} - \ln\left(\sqrt{|w|x} + \sqrt{1 + |w|x}\right) }{ \sqrt{2\mu \, |w|^3} }\tag{1}$$
where $x$ is the separation and $w$ is a negative magic number defined elsewhere in the article.


Unfortunately, this equation seems incorrect (what are the units for $(||)^2+||$, for example?)

$w$ is not a random negative magic number. It is in fact half of the inverse of the semi-major axis length of the orbit, which is negative for a hyperbolic trajectory. This means that $|w|x$ and hence $(||)^2+||$ are unitless.
A good equation to burn into your brain is the vis viva equation,
$$v^2 = \mu\left(\frac2r-\frac1a\right)\tag{2}$$
From this, one can quickly derive that
$$w \equiv \frac1{2a} = 
\frac1r - \frac{v^2}{2\mu}\tag{3}$$
The definition of $w$ on that Wikipedia page uses $x$ instead of $r$. This is a one dimensional problem. Unlike the two dimensional Newtonian two body gravity problem (orbits are in planes, so two dimensional), the one dimensional version is immediately integrable.
Regarding the natural logarithm in equation (1), there's another way to write this due to the relationship between the exponential, hyperbolic, and trigonometric functions:
$$\ln\left(\sqrt z + \sqrt{1+z}\right) \equiv \sinh^{-1}(\sqrt z) \equiv i \sin^{-1}(i\sqrt z)$$
Differentiating equation (1) with respect to time and squaring the result yields equation (2). In other words, the expression is correct -- in the context of Newtonian two body hyperbolic trajectories.

I wasn't being entirely serious with "random magic number" ;-) the answer does at least seem to be "you're holding it wrong", so thankyou for that.
